# Primefaces calendar devuelve fecha erronea

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy utilizando el componente calendar de Primefaces en un proyecto JSF 2.3,
el problema es el siguiente: trabajando con el proyecto desplegado en mi servidor local (Glassfish 4.1), selecciono una fecha y la fecha se guarda en el espacio editable del calendar selecionado ( es decir todo funciona correctamente), pero al copiar el proyecto jsf (todo el proyecto no solo el .war) a otra máquina y desplegar, cuando el usuario interactua con el calendar de cualquiera de las interfaces en que se muestra, este guarda la fecha pero con un día de diferencia respecto al seleccionado, es decir:

Selección del usuario: 22/03/19

El sistema guarda: 21/03/19

Al copiar el mismo servidor en otra pc el problema desaparece, sin embargo, repitiendo esta acción en una tercera, no se solucionó. ¿Qué puede estar fallando?

El código de todos los calendar en mi aplicación es el siguiente:

```
                <div class="ui-g-3">
                    <div class="md-inputfield">
                        <p:calendar id="fecha_fc" value="#{contratacionController.f_costo.fechaCreada}" locale="#{i18nBean.language}" showOn="button" title="#{bundle.CreateFichaCostoLabel_fecha_fc}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateFichaCostoRequiredMessage_fecha_fc}">
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="fecha_ctto"/>
                        </p:calendar>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateFichaCostoLabel_fecha_fc}" for="fecha_fc" />
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/>
               </div>
```

Comment: Hola, puede ser una configuración disteinta en el time zone que están utilizando en sus maquinas, ésto podria provocar esa variación de fecha. Éste link podria darte una idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025116/primefaces-calendar-wrong-date-entry

Comment: Coincido con @cjara. *java.util.Date* contiene información de hora y zona horaria, y al representarse en una zona horaria diferente hace la conversión para representar **ese instante de tiempo** en la zona horaria local. Considera echar un vistazo a las clases de *java.util.time*, en particular *LocalDate*.